# Ubuntu 16.04: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend while trying run python application

Tags: unity, python, opencv

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to run simple python program using OpenCV library. When I try to run PyCharm shows error:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

Here is the my application code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('kura.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

I had the same situation on Ubuntu 17.04. 
After installing 16.04, I only installed: Vivaldi browser, Anaconda for python, PyCharm and Unity Tweak Tools.

My friend is using Xubuntu with XFCE and he don't have such a problem.
Is it possible thet Unity blocks something in system and that is why I can't run program?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934641/glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend-your-settings-will-not-b) the following command should fix your error message

```
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```

but that is not the only reason why your code doesn't work.

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow), `imshow` works only with a `waitKey` call.

The following will work now because the program will wait for user input before closing the image window.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('kura.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```